# Converter that converts videos into a custom video format

Tags: video, image-conversion

I need to make a compressed video format for an 8-bit microcontroller to make a video player. The microcontroller cannot play big formats because they use too much memory and CPU time. I had an idea of my own codec and how the picture should be compressed and decompressed. However, I don't know how to convert videos from other formats which I have no idea about into my own format.

Is there an already existing video converter that passes bitmap data of each frame into my codec algorithm and vice versa?

P.S. I can take care of audio. Audio just needs to be transfered via SPI to an audio codec chip.

Answer (score 3):

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) should be able to do this.

Refer to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342658/ffmpeg-converting-a-video-to-8-bit-bmp-frames) for details

That answer references the command line, but ffmpeg is also available as a library if it's more convenient to you.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org) has a large number of tools for doing almost exactly the sort of thing that you are talking about - you can even use it from within python to read frames into a numpy array, (as [here](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2011/01/converting-video-to-numpy-arrays.html)), use numpy to operate on it and the [write it out to a new video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280653/writing-numpy-arrays-using-cv2-videowriter).